# Compression in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using HBase to store a lot of sensor data.

I have tried to use a txt file to store my sensor data, for a 20MB file, if I compress it, it will reduce to 1MB on disk.

My question is: Does HBase itself do compression automatically when storing the data to disks?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use lzo, gzip or snappy for hbase compression.  You will need to set lzo/snappy yourself if you wish to use them for hbase compression (gzip is included).

normally - lzo is faster than gzip compression though gzip compression ratio normally be better.  Snappy is robust with compression but compression ratios are normally worse.

When creating a table - you can specify compression/compression library - hfiles are compressed when written to disk if compression is used (and need to be decompressed when reading).

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also alter your table to add compression support later. Then your data will be compressed for real at the next compaction (as ali said, because a new HFile will be written to disk).
As far as I understand, compression algorithm is used at the block-level, not at the whole HFile. That mean that when reading data, it won't have to uncompress a several-GBs HFile but only a few KBs data block.